# Declaring Objective-C constant strings accessible by subclass

Tags: objective-c

With all the new Objective-C features, what is the best way to declare a const string and make accessible to subclassess? (Do I use properties, and if so, what is the best way to assign it once - NOT everytime the object is instantiated?)

Comment: The common design pattern for *initialize once, use often* is Singleton..

Comment: If I declare as property, it becomes instance variables. The other way is to use global constants, like this http://iphonesdkbasics.blogspot.jp/2010/06/declaring-constants-in-objective-c.html or http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/java-developers-guide-to-string-constants-in-objective-c.html - under the 'Public String Constants Using ‘extern’' section.

Comment: There is no equivalent of Java's protected static variables in Objective-C, right?